# retrieve data from sql query by listbox multiple selected items and display in graph

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox, items

I'm trying to retrieve data by multiple selected items in listbox but I can only retrieve one item. I need help?

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;


SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarih1", convert);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarih2", convert2);
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
chart1.Titles.Add("DC POWER" + " ( " + convert + "  -  " + convert2 + " ) ");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


//Drawing Graph
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{

    chart1.DataSource = cmd;
    string query = "SELECT AVG(carpim ) as " + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + " FROM (SELECT AVG(" + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + ") AS carpim FROM se_dc_power INNER JOIN  poa ON se_dc_power.dc_pwr_date = poa.poa_date  inner join se_modules_temp on dc_pwr_date = modules_temp_date  and dc_pwr_date between @Tarih1 and @Tarih2 and TEMP_" + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + "      is not null  and poa_south is not null and  poa_south>0 and  se_dc_power." + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + ">0       and se_dc_power." + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + "    is not null group by dc_pwr_date having AVG(" + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + ")>10       and AVG(poa_south)>50)x";
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    chart1.Series.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
    chart1.Series[i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    chart1.Series[i].LegendText = listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString();

    chart1.Series[i].YValueMembers = listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString();
    chart1.Series[i].ToolTip = listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString();
    chart1.Series[i].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
    query = "";

}
```

Comment: This sql is pretty scary. It is vulnerable to sql injection even though you have some parameters in there.

Comment: In each loop, you are overwriting the query for your SqlDataAdapter but you do not execute the query each time. I'm assuming that call happens below the `FOR` loop...? If you would like to execute it for each selected item, ou need to move that call to execute the query (e.g. `da.Fill(..)`) inside the loop.

Comment: Since you are only returning one value each time, maybe you should use a SqlCommand ExecuteScalar.        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @J.D. aactually I did'nt use da.fill, if it's possible can you send an execute applied code

Comment: Can you edit your post then to show the line(s) of code where you get the results from the SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: @J.D. I added that to chart not a table ?